# Rate Limiting Endpoints using flask-limiter

Tags: flask-restplus

I know and love `flask-limiter` from older projects. Now I want to use it on my `flask-restplus` based project.

My ultimate solution would enable me, to do rate limiting on a per method level. So different rates apply to a post than to a get method.
But I would already be happy if I could define the limits on a per Resource (or even per Namespace) level. 
Important is that each resource would need its own rate limit.

My first try was to annotate the methods using `@limiter.limit("1 per Minute")`. But that is completely ignored.

Next try than is using it on the namespace itself:

```
ns = api.namespace('something',
    description='Operations related to maps and positions on a map',
    decorators = [limiter.limit("1 Per Minute")]
)
```

Well, does not work either. But

```
ns = api.namespace('something',
    description='Operations related to maps and positions on a map',
    decorators = [limiter.limit]
)
```

does the thing. But leaves one problem open: I can only define one limiter per app. So I can only apply one limit rule to all my namespaces.

Any ideas on how I could make `flask-restplus` accept the params passed to the limiter-decorator?

Or is there even a better way to manage rate-limiting in flask-resplus that I just did not see?