# Flask-Limiter is not called on Flask-Restful API's method_decorators

Tags: python, flask, python-3.8, flask-restful, flask-limiter

I've tried to follow some questions with no luck:

- [Flask-Limiter does not work with Flask-Restful API-based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369112/flask-limiter-does-not-work-with-flask-restful-api-based-application)
- [Rate Limiting Endpoints using flask-limiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061006/rate-limiting-endpoints-using-flask-limiter)

Due to `outside of context` issue I created a `limiter` function in a util.py file as follow:

```
def limiter():
    _limiter = Limiter(
        app,
        key_func=get_remote_address
    )
    return _limiter
```

And in my Flask-Restful API resource I have called this limiter in `method-decorators`:

```
from ..utils import limiter

class UsersView(Resource, CustomAPIMixin):
     method_decorators = [limiter().limit("1/minute", methods=["GET"])]

     @jwt_authenticate()
     def get(self):
         user_id = get_jwt_identity()
         return self.api_response(content={"user_id": user_id})
```

**NOTE:** I'm using `Flask version 2` and `Flask-Limiter 1.4`

---

**EDIT-1:**

```
my_api
    models
    scripts
    views
         users.py
    __init__.py  # contains create_app() to return Flask app
    utils.py. # contains custom rate_limit() function
```

---

**EDIT-2:**
Here is the full working code that *Flask-Limiter* does not work on:

- https://github.com/alirezastack/ratelimit_api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flask-Limiter documentation gives an example that fits this case: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#using-flask-pluggable-views

If you set `decorators` instead of `method_decorators` it should fix your issue.

Here is a fully working sample that demonstrates rate limiting for the provided code.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


def limiter():
    _limiter = Limiter(
        app,
        key_func=get_remote_address
    )
    return _limiter


class CustomAPIMixin:
    def api_response(self, content):
        return content


def get_jwt_identity():
    return 0


class UsersView(Resource, CustomAPIMixin):
    decorators = [limiter().limit("1/minute", methods=["GET"])]

    # @jwt_authenticate()
    def get(self):
        user_id = get_jwt_identity()
        return self.api_response(content={"user_id": user_id})


api.add_resource(UsersView, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This is weird that your code works in a separate file, but when I put in my own code structure I get no errors for rate limit!

Comment: Please check *Edit-1* for more info.

Comment: I would need a minimal example that doesn't work correctly to find out why it's not working. Otherwise I can't be sure I found the same problem that you have.

Comment: Please kindly check this repo that ratelimit does not work on: https://github.com/alirezastack/ratelimit_api

Comment: In your code you are initializing the limiter with an uninitialized current_app. You need to pass the app to the limiter.
Hope this helps. Otherwise, create another question and include all relevant information so that it can be useful to other SO users.

Comment: You mean in __init__ of View class? Because otherwise I have imported current_app in `utils.py` and used current_app in `Flask-Limiter`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: From the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-context), `current_app` should not be available from `utils.py` unless you import it in a context. For a quick solution set `ProfileView.decorators` in `app_routes` function where you have the `app` available.

Comment: +1 That solved the isuue! Thanks. :) so it was a false understanding that in utils.py I have access to my current ongoing app context.